# Determine if server is listening when using udp

Tags: c#, asynchronous, network-programming, udp

**The setting:** I want to write a point-to-point `Connection` class that, when used, does not differentiate between server and client. The first host which calls `connect()` shall become the server waiting for the client to connect and the second shall become the client that connects to the server.

In order to do that the `connect()` method first needs to check for a listening server. **a)** The first time this happens no server is found and the party calling `connect()` starts listening on `localhost` and the configured port for an incoming connection. **b)** The second party calling `connect()` also checks the remote host on the given port, recognizes the server and connects to it.

This is not too hard using TCP since `TcpClient.Connect()` throws an exception when no connection could be established. Therefore I know when I'm the first. Since I use reliable LAN only, I wanted to use UDP, however.

**My problem:**  How can I determine whether an UDP server socket is waiting for incoming data.

Ideally I would like to use the asynchronous network API directly afterwards. Instead of dealing with listening threads all by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With UDP, the communication model is akin to a message in a bottle: you know you sent it, but there's no way to know if anyone ever received it.

You need to manually establish a communication protocol to determine if the remote party is listening (e.g. have them send a "Yes, I 'm here" response). This would require *both* endpoints to accept UDP datagrams.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon and Andrew said you can't see if a listener is open, but you can implement a ping/pong protocol.   Send a ping first time you connect if no pong back then set this up like a server.
If you got pong back then that's your server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can check for a listening server, short of sending a packet and waiting to see if you get a reply.